# Google Test Check for Float Not Equality

Tags: c++, googletest

Is there an expectation for a float value not being equal to the second value?

E.g the opposite of EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ(val1,val2)

Comment: do you want to check for exact equality or for `abs(val1 - val2) > eps`? If it is the second you could assert for directly that expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think GTest has this functionality, they explain in their [documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#floating-point-predicate-format-functions)

> Some floating-point operations are useful, but not that often used. In order to avoid an explosion of new macros, we provide them as predicate-format functions that can be used in predicate assertion macros (e.g. EXPECT_PRED_FORMAT2, etc).

You can define a predicate, as suggested by @idclev 463035818, and pass it into the `EXPECT_PRED_FORMAT2(pred, val1, val2)`. The predicate must conform to the signature:

```
testing::AssertionResult pred(const char* expr1, const char* expr2,
                                    double val1, double val2);
```

Where `expr1` & `expr2` are the string representation of the float arguments that will be used in the assertion messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Mock's floating point [matchers](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md#floating-point-matchers-fpmatchers). They can be easily composed into more complex assertions:

```
EXPECT_THAT(val1, Not(DoubleEq(val2)))
```